# python and email.utils - How to add CC list

Tags: python

How do I format a CC list i the below?

should I add 'CC: test@test.com;test1@test.com'?

```
  CC = ['test@test.com','test1@test.com']



  header = 'To:' + TO_ADDRESS + '\n' + 'From: ' + FROM_ADDRESS + '\n' + 'Subject:' + SUB_ADD + '\n'
  msg = header + '\n' + TEXT_INSERT'server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
  server.ehlo()
  server.starttls()
  server.ehlo()
  server.login(FROM_ADDRESS, PASSWORD)
  server.sendmail(FROM_ADDRESS, TO_ADDRESS, msg)
  server.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add the CC addresses to both the headers (`header`) *and* the envelope (`SMTP.sendmail(..., to_addrs, ...)`).